# Display items from the database in a chart

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to display the average of results for each exam paper in a graph. my problem is that when I catch the data from my database I stored it in an array so that I couldn't print these values as a list of array such as  `["a","b","c","d","e"]` or `[44,100,50.29,100]` to use it in var xValues and var yValues , I also tried to use `foreach`, but it doesn't work. Please help.

/* Here is JS code  */

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var xValues =<?php foreach($examPapertitle as $title) {
                        echo $title;
                        }; ?>
                        
    var yValues =<?php foreach($avgcountresult as $average) {
                        echo $average;
                        }; ?>
    var barColors = ["red", "green","blue","orange","brown"];

    new Chart("myChart", {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: xValues,
        datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: barColors,
          data: yValues
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {display: false},
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Average of Results"
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

/* Here is HTML Code */

```
$examPapertitle=array();
$avgcountresult= array();
$fetchresult = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT AVG(results.percentage), exam_paper.examTitle FROM results INNER JOIN exam_paper ON results.examPaperID = exam_paper.examPaperID GROUP by results.examPaperID ORDER by results.examPaperID");
while($rowresult= mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchresult)){
    $examPapertitle[] = $rowresult['examTitle'];
    $avgcountresult[] = $rowresult['AVG(results.percentage)'];
}


<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that your `var xValues =`  needs an input of let's say `[44,100,50.29,100]` and instead you are echoing `4410050.29100`

So you need to `echo` those values correctly, you can either change your php block like so:

```
var xValues =[<?php foreach($examPapertitle as $k=>$title) {
                        echo $title.($k>0?",":"");
                        }; ?>]
```

Or to use much easier to read functions:

```
var xValues =[<?php echo implode($examPapertitle,",") ?>]
```

This is if your values are numbers, you will need to wrap those values in quotes for strings, like so:

```
var xValues =["<?php echo implode($examPapertitle,'","') ?>"]
```

If you need more info about how implode works, you can check it's manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

PS: a handy tip when mixing php and javascript is to always check your php's output (aka the browser source file) through the web inspector. It makes it much easier to catch issues like this.

Comment: `var xValues =["<?php echo implode($examPapertitle,'","') ?>"] ' works thank you so much